# RNGoogleSignin tried to override RNGoogleSigninModule ERROR

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to build authentication with Google in my React-Native app. Whenever I run the app it displays this error saying that there is a duplicate but in fact, there is no duplicate.

[image]

Environment:

```
- react-native 0.60.4
- react-native-google-signin 2.0.0

-----------------------------------------------
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
       minSdkVersion = 16
       compileSdkVersion = 28
       targetSdkVersion = 28
       supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
       googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"

  classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0')
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Is there no duplicate in the Mainapplication.java file?

Comment: @hongdevelop there is no duplicate

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: share your mainapplication.java

Comment: You might have conflicting packages in your `package.json`, can you share that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using `react-native > 0.6`.
And in versions `> 0.6`, packages are automatically linked.

So remove the package that you manually added for `MainApplication.java`, and then try to build and run it again. This should solve your problem.

```java
// MainApplication.java

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // your package might be added here. Remove (only) that package.
  return packages;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I'm using react-native 0.61.5, but MainApplication.java not contains particular package name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like youre using the old package, [react-native-google-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin), you should use [@react-native-community/google-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/google-signin) since you're using RN>=0.6. Many repo's were moved into the `react-native-community` organisation on Github.

Try `npm rm react-native-google-signin`, **then** `npm i @react-native-community/google-signin`.